# My second function is not removing the parent element

Tags: javascript, jquery

HTML

```
<form action="form.php" method="post">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Query string</legend>
        <div class="query_string">
            <div class="parameter">
                <label for="parameter_1">Parameter</label>
                <input type="text" id="parameter_1" required="required" />
            </div>
            <div class="argument">
                <label for="argument_1">Argument</label>
                <input type="text" id="argument_1" required="required" />
            </div> <a href="#" class="add_query_string">➕</a>

        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var x = 1;

    $(".add_query_string").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        x++;
        $('\
            <div class="query_string">\
                <div class="parameter">\
                    <label for="parameter_' + x + '">Parameter</label>\
                    <input type="text" id="parameter_' + x + '" required="required"/>\
                </div>\
                \
                <div class="argument">\
                    <label for="argument_' + x + '">Argument</label>\
                    <input type="text" id="argument_' + x + '" required="required"/>\
                </div>\
                \
                <a href="#" class="remove_query_string">➖</a>\
            </div>').insertAfter(".query_string:last");
    });

    $(".remove_query_string").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent("div").remove();
        x--;
    });

});
```

[Link to the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/defaye/qbzejta8/)
I'm having difficulty getting my second function to work. I'm not sure why.

Comment: @Juhana so I need to use `on` instead? Will I get into trouble selecting multiple instances of the class `query_string`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are adding the elements dynamically, which means the element was not present while your script ran, and hence doesn't have an event handler. You can use jQuery [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on) method to delegate the event handler to a static parent element as follows:

```
$(document).on("click",".remove_query_string",function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent("div").remove();
    x--;
});
```

Comment: `$(document).` is the sole thing I was missing in earlier revisions of the code when I was trying something like `$(".query_string").on("click", ".remove_query_string", function(e) { ... });`... ah!

Comment: @defaye `document` is just an example... it is better to use the closest static parent element, in your case probably the `<form>` so that the event will reach it quickly..

Comment: So basically `$(".query_string")` was not working because it was dynamically created, and I have to select something already in the DOM? I think I've understood my error now.

Comment: That is what i mentioned in the answer... `$(".query_string")` finds nothing when your script which attaches the handler runs... If you add the element later it will not have a handler since it was not there when you tried to attach the handler...